# Perform backup (and restore) from my current LFS (Linux From Scratch) progress with dd command

Tags: dd, lfs

I have my LFS proyek, currently I'm in chapter 10 so far according this book `https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter10/grub.html` .

I want to perform backup of my LFS progress so if there's mistake I can restore its checkpoint, currently my LFS progress and its content are saved in `/dev/vdb`. I have umounted `dev/vdb` , now I want to copy or backup all content in `/dev/vdb` with `dd` command and give format name `backupLFS.disk` so it will be safely saved in LFS Host (in my case is ubuntu), but I realized it's dangerous enough if I wrong put parameter mainly confused with `of` and `if`. So what should I do?

Comment: `/dev/vdb` strongly suggests that your LFS system is a VM.  If vdb is a qcow2 file, LVM partition, a file on a btrfs mount, or a file on a zfs dataset or a zfs zvol then the easiest and fastest method would be to just make a snapshot (you'd do this on the VM host, not on the VM guest).  It's easy to revert to a snapshot at any time, and you can also copy/clone them easily for use with other VMs if needed.

Comment: BTW, if you can't or don't want to make a snapshot, there are far better tools than `dd` to make an image copy of a partition.   [partimage](http://www.partimage.org), for example, can easily make a compressed partition backup that ignores all the unused/empty space in the filesystem on the partition.  From `man partimage`: *Supported file systems: Ext2/3, Reiser3, FAT16/32, HPFS, JFS, XFS, UFS(beta), HFS(beta), NTFS(experimental)*.  There's also [partclone](http://partclone.org) which supports even more fs types.

Answer (score 0):

The backup itself is easy - in general `in=<input-file>`, `of=<output-file>`:

```
# dd if=/dev/vdb of=/path/to/backup/storage/my_lfs.img
```

Then you can tweak some options like `bs=<block-size>` (to make blocks which dd copies different, usually bigger, which should speed up operation., `status=progress` (for progress) and so on.

`if=/dev/vdb` will also save it as whole drive, with partition table and then partitions. If, in case, you wanted to access these partitions you have to get their offsets.

Comment: I mounted ```/dev/vdb1``` then check with ```df -ah```, it shown ```/dev/vdb1``` size is about 2G, But when I tried backup with ```dd if=/dev/vdb1 of=LFS.iso``` why ```LFS.iso``` became 5G

Comment: You can check you block devices with `lsblk`, `fdisk /dev/vdb` (or `cfdisk` for that matter), even `df` on mounted filesystems.